# Cant access SqlConnection from a method

Tags: c#, sql

i cant seem to access my SqlConnection from another method. I have the connection creation with in the main form. I am trying to reuse it in the loadAdminTable method.

I am unsure what i should be including or changing to allow it to be accessed in this method. Any help or good direction will be great. Thanks

***MainForm***

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
```

***Method trying to use the connection***

```
public void loadAdminTable()
        {
           SqlCommand cmdDatabase1 = new SqlCommand("Select * from Admin", con);

            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
                sda1.SelectCommand = cmdDatabase1;
                DataTable dbdataset1 = new DataTable();
                sda1.Fill(dbdataset1);
                BindingSource bSource1 = new BindingSource();

                bSource1.DataSource = dbdataset1;
                adminGridView.DataSource = bSource1;
                sda1.Update(dbdataset1);

                adminGridView.Columns[0].Width = 92;
                adminGridView.Columns[1].Width = 200;
                adminGridView.Columns[2].Width = 180;
                adminGridView.Columns[3].Width = 180;
                adminGridView.Columns[4].Width = 170;
                adminGridView.Columns[5].Width = 130;
                adminGridView.Columns[6].Width = 170;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Are your method `loadAdminTable` and the connection variable `con ` in the same namespace? Or can `con` be accessed from the method?

Comment: You haven't opened a connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your sqlconnection & sqlcommand and paste it in your try block. Now every-time you declare SqlConnection you need not write it explicitly. It will get connection string from App.Config file. I think it will serve your purpose....

```
    SqlConnection conn =new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString);


    conn.Open();
    string query = ""Select * from Admin"";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    DataTable t1 = new DataTable();
    using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        a.Fill(t1);
    }
    BindingSource bSource1 = new BindingSource();

    bSource1.DataSource = dbdataset1;
    adminGridView.DataSource = bSource1;
    sda1.Update(dbdataset1);

    adminGridView.Columns[0].Width = 92;
    adminGridView.Columns[1].Width = 200;
    adminGridView.Columns[2].Width = 180;
    adminGridView.Columns[3].Width = 180;
    adminGridView.Columns[4].Width = 170;
    adminGridView.Columns[5].Width = 130;
    adminGridView.Columns[6].Width = 170;
```

<------- Add this below block to App.config file----------->

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionStringName"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
      connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the signature of the method to

```
public void loadAdminTable(con)
```

and all should work. Providing you open the connection